# Windows 7 User/Personal folder

Tags: windows-7, user-folders

Is located on "C:/Users/Leandro".

I want to know if it's possible to stop Windows from automatically creating new folders. I have created my own folders for specific stuff but everytime I do "anything" I find out Windows created 5 new folders Like "search", "contacts", "shortcuts", etc.

How do I stop this behaviour?

A second question attached here is something realated:

On the main menu, my Leandro/Personal folder appears as a menu.

Is it possible to change the Directory of what the menu shows, because as I stated before it shows 5 more folders (or even more) and makes it harder to find the ones I use.

Comment: Seems to be related to the new "Libraries" in Windows 7. Where are the new folders appearing? Just on the sidebar menu?

Comment: YES on sidebar menu and also on the folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer to 1. Question:

These folders are part of your profile. You can relocate them individually to another path like `C:\Users\Leandro\Windows\Search` or `C:\Users\Leandro\Windows\Contacts` via Context Menu => Properties => Location; it's the only way to change this permanently.

But I think it's much better to separate your personal data from the operating system drive! I think it is stupid that Windows systems store everything on the same partition. Microsoft also doesn't offer an option to move the entire user profile folder to another partition.

You should manage your personal data on another partition. You can relocate "My Documents", "My Music", etc. to do that.

Comment: +1 for seperating personal folders from the drive with the OS on

Comment: You should give the reason when recommending something like storing personal files on a separate partition. I personally don't see any reason to partition, especially not for small things like drive optimization. It may be useful for niche cases like multiple operating systems.

Comment: There are multiple reasons to separate your data from the systems. Some of them are less risk on reinstalling after system fails, save and easy backup & recovery (restoring a system with an image without override user files, no need for high frequently backups for the whole system, easy file backups for your user files), less fragmentation on the system disk, less usage of SSDs for longer lifespan, using a SSD for the system which needs performance and storing your data on an big HDD (or RAID) which needs space,... Its just a shame Windows is the only (!) OS which can't do that transparent.